# Which site is best for questions about web security?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Specifically, I am referring to this question:

> **How to indicate that content in an iframe is untrusted**
>
> As part of a website I am developing, untrusted content is displayed in a sandboxed iframe. The content is loaded using the `srcdoc` attribute, but the iframe is sandboxed using `sandbox="allow-scripts"`, so the untrusted content does not have same-origin access. However, I am concerned about malicious scripts running within the iframe. Particularly, I am concerned about phishing, since the domain displayed in the addressbar will be my website, and things like malicious alert() messages. What is a good way to either avoid this issue in the first place, or make it clear to visitors that the content is untrusted? (I can't turn off the allow-scripts permission because there are legitimate scripts that need to run in the content).

Currently posted [on Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92881/how-to-indicate-that-content-in-an-iframe-is-untrusted).

Are questions about web security best for [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com) or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)

Answer (score 4):

This kind of question would be suitable for Security.SE, as it relates to usable security.  It might also get useful answers on UX.SE, as those folks are experts in usability, user experience, and user behavior.  So, I recommend you decide between those two.

The way you should decide between Security.SE and UX.SE is: do you want your question to be seen by security experts, or by UX experts?    If it were me, I would probably ask on Security.SE, given that your focus is primarily on the security angle, but you can decide for yourself what you are looking for.

Make sure you explain in your question what research you've done, what resources you've found, what considerations you've already found, and your reaction to them.  Yes, this requires you to do a significant amount of research on your own before asking -- but that is always good practice and increases the likelihood you will get useful answers to your question.

I see you've already posted your question on Security.SE.  If you decide UX.SE is a better fit, don't re-post your question on UX.SE as well.  Cross-posting is [frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info).  Instead, you can click "flag" to flag your post for moderator attention and ask them to migrate it elsewhere.

I would not recommend asking on Stack Overflow.  In this kind of situation, Stack Overflow will be better for questions where you know what you want to achieve it but you're not sure how to achieve it (e.g., how to implement it).

Answer (score 1):

Going on your title solely, I would expect this question on UX Stack Exchange, since it has nothing to do with the actual software, more about how to make this clear to the user. The question body isn't really helpful to the question in my opinion. It gives some context, but doesn't relate to the question on top.

So my bet would be on UX Stack Exchange. On SO I wouldn't probably vote to close such a question.